# undefined response on angularjs $resource.save.$promise callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm triying to make post on an API. One of the values i have to get it from a dropdown which is filled from a json. This is the part of the code where i get the values from json:

```
function comboNation (){
  $http.get('app/componentes/comboProcedence.json')
    .then(function(data){
      vm.nation = data.data;
    //console.log(vm.nation);
  });
}
```

**EDIT** And the response are just two values. This is the Json data:

```
    [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "value": "National"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "value": "International"
  }
]
```

The html view:

```
<div class="col-md-4">Procedence
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="options2" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
    {{$ctrl.btnProcedence}} 
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="list2">
    <li  ng-repeat="alo in $ctrl.nation">
      <a href="#" ng-click="$ctrl.getWhereIs(alo)">{{alo.value}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now, with the next code, i'm getting the selected value:

```
vm.btnProcedence = "Select one";

vm.getWhereIs = function(f){
  vm.isThere = f.Id;
  vm.btnProcedence = f.value;
  //console.log(vm.isThere);
}

vm.idDoc = vm.isThere;
```

On the console log, i print the selected value with `vm.isThere`. As you can see, is nested on the `ng-click`. At this point, it works fine, but when im triying to make the post, the selected value is *undefined*.

This is the part of the code where i'm making the post:

```
vm.travelData = function() {
  var data = {
    Name: vm.name,
    IdDocumentType: vm.idDoc,
  };
  loadInfo(data);
  console.log(data);
};

function loadInfo(data) {
  var arr = {
    Name: vm.name,
    IdDocumentType: vm.idDoc,
  };
  postInfo.save(arr).$promise
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Html view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.travelData()">Send Info</button>
```

Someone knows why is undefined?

The response of the api is true, so, there's no error message.

Hope you can help me.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you actualizar your question with the JSON data?

Comment: Post your comboProcedence too.

Comment: Done! i put my json data

Comment: @ChuckVillavicencio `vm.idDoc = vm.isThere;` must be inside the `vm.getWhereIs` function. Also: `vm.name` is `undefined`.

Comment: Such a fool i am. Thanks for your answer, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vm.idDoc = vm.isThere;` must be inside the `vm.getWhereIs` function. Also: `vm.name` is `undefined`.

See this example:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);
  app.controller("Controller", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.nation = [{
        "Id": 1,
        "value": "National"
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "value": "International"
      }
    ];

    $scope.btnProcedence = "Select one";

    $scope.getWhereIs = function(f) {
      $scope.isThere = f.Id;
      $scope.btnProcedence = f.value;
      $scope.idDoc = $scope.isThere;
      $scope.name = "A name...";
    };

    $scope.travelData = function() {
      var data = {
        Name: $scope.name,
        IdDocumentType: $scope.idDoc,
      };
      loadInfo(data);
    };

    function loadInfo(data) {
      var arr = {
        Name: $scope.name,
        IdDocumentType: $scope.idDoc,
      };
      console.log(arr);

      /* postInfo.save(arr).$promise
         .then(function(response) {
           console.log(response);
         });
         */
    }
  }]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app">
  <div data-ng-controller="Controller">
    <div class="col-md-4">Procedence
      <br>
      <button type="button" id="options2" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
    {{btnProcedence}} 
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="list2">
        <li ng-repeat="alo in nation">
          <a href="#" data-ng-click="getWhereIs(alo)">{{alo.value}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="travelData()">Send Info</button>

  </div>
</div>
```